# VFS is not working after migrating from wso2-mi-1.2 to wso2-mi-4.0

Tags: wso2

We have a bit of file processing involved. Which is addressed using a proxy service and VFS Transport Listener. It works fine with Wso2-mi-1.2, however, the same proxy-service doesn't get invoked at all with wso2-mi-4.0

I have checked axis2.xml,transportSender and transportReceiver for VFS are already uncommented.

```
    <transportReceiver name="vfs" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener">

    <transportSender name="vfs" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportSender">
```

I can see the synapse-vfs*.jar and commons-vfs2*.jar in the wso2/components/plugins directory as well.

Any kind of help is really appreciated.

Comment: Did you see any error logs on MI while deploying the proxy service?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it, no errors.

Comment: I have tested the sample given in MI 4.0.0 in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/examples/file-processing/vfs-transport-examples/. This works fine. Can you share your use case or artifacts?